# Debug node.js web application that has been launched via a Gulp task

Tags: node.js, debugging, gulp, webstorm

I have a web application that is written in node.js and gets started using a gulp command. When the application first starts, before the server is running, debug points may be hit in WebStorm (or in any IDE or command line tool). However, after the server is running and I go to the interface in my localhost I can no longer hit debug points inside the application. This is not being caused by client side code as the debug points are in server code.

I have read the answers that involve using the node-inspector and that has not solved my problem because of configuration files that are not getting read when starting the debugger in node inspector.

I'm a bit surprised that there is so little on here about this issue. Is it not a normal problem that other developers face? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround for this may not be sufficient for every case. I was modifying JavaScript files and didn't actually need the configuration files, after loading, to be able to test my changes. I did the following:

1. Wrote a line in my app.js file that set the variables I needed. (these would have been tasks ran in Gulp)
2. I then started the app as a Node.js app and was able to debug it as normal.

If any of my views had been updated, or anything else that was being managed by Gulp, then I could have simply stopped the server, started it again via the Gulp command, and then stopped again and restarted as a Node.js app.

This did not solve the issue in my OP but it was a good enough workaround to get debug points in the JavaScript.